# How to integrate Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit with user interface?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add an image cropper to my app and have found [Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit](https://github.com/muak/Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit), that seems to be a good way to start on it, but the problem is that I couldn't find any example of how to show the image and the square over it to cut the image, in other words, integrate it with UI. Does anyone here have used ImageEdit and can tell me how to do it?

What I have so far:

```
async void Init()
        {
            MediaFile a = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
            {
                CompressionQuality = 80,
                RotateImage = true
            });

            byte[] imageArray = await Task.Run(()=>ImagePath2ByteArray(a));

            using (var image = await CrossImageEdit.Current.CreateImageAsync(imageArray))
            {
                var croped = await Task.Run(() =>
                        image.Crop(10, 20, 250, 100)
                             .Rotate(180)
                             .Resize(100, 0)
                             .ToPng()
                );
            }
        }

        async Task<byte[]> ImagePath2ByteArray(MediaFile a)
        {
            byte[] imageArray = null;
            if (a != null)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var stream = a.GetStream();
                    stream.CopyTo(ms);
                    imageArray = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return imageArray;
        }
```

It seems to work fine but doesn't have UI.

Comment: see the sample: https://github.com/muak/PanPinchSample

Comment: @Jason I saw this sample, but it doesn't compiles here and I didn't understand 100% its code. I thought I could implement it more simply.

Comment: if all you need is cropping, try https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms

Comment: @Jason are you using Image Cropper 1.0.6? Here it shows this error ```Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile> Plugin.Media.Abstractions.IMedia.TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions)```, I have permissions for using camera/storage, I have added all the needed lines to android manifest and also to MainActivity.

Comment: @Jason fixed by installing ImageCropper.Forms.Fix